# `per-instance` event is executed on every boot in COS

Tags: cloud-init, google-container-optimized-os

I am using Container Optimized OS and `cloud-init` script to run a service as a container. I have a script which format Persistent Drive device with ext4 file system. This script is under `per-instance` folder:

```yaml
write_files:
  - path: /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-instance/fs-prepare.sh
    permissions: 0544
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      
      mkfs.ext4 -L data -m 0 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard /dev/disk/by-id/google-data
```

But it executes every time I reboot the instance and wipe out data. Log file indicates that during the boot, `cloud-init` does not see cache and decides it is the first boot of the instance:

```
handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: init-local/check-cache: attempting to read from cache [check]
util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /var/lib/cloud/instance/obj.pkl (quiet=False)
stages.py[DEBUG]: no cache found
handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-local/check-cache: SUCCESS: no cache found
```

This corresponds to GCP's COS [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/disks-and-filesystem), which lists `/var/lib/cloud` as stateless mount. Which brings up the question, how `per-instance` even suppose to work in COS if COS discards whole state of `cloud-init` on every reboot?